# How to position an image of different size using css?

Tags: css, sass

I have two images of different width and height that need to be positioned bottom centered within the image box. Here is the HTML and CSS example.

```
<div class="box">
     <div class='image'>
        <img alt="" src="image.jpg"/>
     </div>
</div>

.box {
  max-width: 970px;
  height: 440px;
}
.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

This code works fine for a large image of exact width and height. But when a smaller image is placed within image box, that image is centered bottom right. How can I make both images center bottom?

Thanks for anyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go... I'll try to explain as we go, but short answer, [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philwills/dw5xQ/2/)

```
.box {
  /* Just so I could see the parent */
  background-color: #bada55;
  max-width: 970px;
  height: 440px;
  /* Needed to make this element positional (so it will contain the absolutely positioned child */
  position: relative;
  /* Yep, center wasn't necessary here... */
}
.box .image { /* move this to the image wrapper */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  /* Force full width */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* Center contents (the image) */
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Phillips. This works great. However, I forgot to mention that the image is within the iframe in an external html document, which has the fixed width of 989 x 600, and with you code the image is position center bottom correctly, but within the .box not within the iframe:(. I forgot to mention this before I even posted this question. Apology. So, what I've done is set the height of the .box to 495px and that way positioned the image relative to iframe. How would you do it? Thanks ever so much for your help!

Comment: So if the structure is iframe>.box>.image>IMG just take position: relative off of .box.

Answer (score 0):

I found this semantic trick to work pretty well (without any absolute positions)

```
.box {
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
max-width: 970px;
height: 440px;
border:2px solid red;
}

.box .something-semantic {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.box .something-else-semantic {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

html

```
<div class="box">
<div class="something-semantic">
<div class="something-else-semantic">
  <img src="" width="50" height="40"/>
  <img src="" width="120" height="70"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4DBxq/)

Comment: This is basically using a table for formatting... even though you're not using the table tag, you're essentially making the div a table with the styling (better than using table, but still not good).